# Do Webkit Browsers wait for an indexedDB transaction being flushed to disk?

Tags: browser, webkit, indexeddb

Mozilla states in their Firefox documentation that since Version 40 the `complete` event gets fired before data has been flushed to disk. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction). How are the other browsers handling that - specifically Webkit based browsers?

> Note that as of Firefox 40, IndexedDB transactions have relaxed durability guarantees to increase performance (see bug 1112702.) Previously in a readwrite transaction IDBTransaction.oncomplete was fired only when all data was guaranteed to have been flushed to disk. In Firefox 40+ the complete event is fired after the OS has been told to write the data but potentially before that data has actually been flushed to disk.

Comment: I can't comment for WebKit. Chrome currently (47) does not fire "complete" until the data has been flushed. There is no spec requirement either way. There has been some discussion about adding control over this to the API, and defining the required behavior in a future version of the spec.